# How to select a dropdown option by its text in newer version of JQuery?

Tags: jquery, select

I used to select a dropdown option using the following statement:

```
$('select#someId option[text="B"]');
```

for the select element as below:

```
<select id="someId">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
</select>
```

But it seems like the same statement doesn't work in newer versions of jQuery. I'm using the version 1.7. What is the best way to achieve that in the newer version of jQuery?

Comment: I don't know how that example jQuery snippet could ever have worked in any version.

Comment: FYI The IDs still do not match :)

Comment: the selector is someId not someID

Comment: They are just typos guys... just corrected them. Thanks ;)

Comment: The bigger issue with the original (besides the syntax errors) is that you're using the attribute selector on a property. Hence why I can't understand how this could ever work originally.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter:

```
$('select#someId option').filter(function(){ return this.text == "B" }).html("BLAH!");
```

In your case you want to set the select `val` using the `val` of the matching option:

```
$('select#someId').val($('select#someId option').filter(function(){ return this.text == "B" }).val());
```

Note: You have some syntax errors in your example (because of nested quotes):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vokxtvLj/1/

Comment: Good catch on the syntax error. They were just typo and has been corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#someId").val($("#someId" + " option").filter(function() { return this.text === 'B' }).val());
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68fk26xy/)